# Managing Income to Facilitate Taking Tax-free Capital Gains

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, tax-loss-harvesting

Regarding Capital Gains Tax in U.S.:

I am retired, and my only income is what I think is called "passive", e.g. RMDs, dividends, interest, and realized capital gains.  My understanding is that if my ("regular"? "ordinary"?) income is under about $40K, I can then take long-term capital gains at a zero tax rate.  Is that generally correct?

Some notes:

- With regard to my brokerage accounts, pretty much all of my dividends and interest are reinvested.
- If I understand correctly, absent any realized capital gains (long or short), my ("regular"? "ordinary"?) income then consists of my RMDs, interest generated from savings accounts, and any/all "qualified" dividends even if automatically reinvested.
- My question, for simplicity's sake, ignores any loss harvesting in the same year.

Comment: Reinvested earnings of any kind are taxed the same as if you took them in cash. Interest and _unqualified_ dividends are taxed as ordinary income, but _qualified_ dividends and long-term cap gains are taxed at lower rates. If your ordinary income less deduction is less than $40,400 for single or MFS in 2021 (different for other statuses or other years) the LTCG+QD that fit between that amount and the breakpoint is tax-free; above that it is 15% and above a higher limit 20%. Dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/146080/ and https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110332/

Comment: Added: also if you're over RMD age you probably should be getting Social Security; remember that if you have significant other income in addition to SS it may make part of your SS taxable -- and if so, it is ordinary income in the tax calculation.

Comment: Note: I'm not "RMD age" yet...RMDs mentioned are from an inheritance IRA.  But good thought to mention.  And your response helped me also find this link: https://www.kiplinger.com/taxes/tax-planning/602187/how-to-possibly-pay-0-in-taxes-on-your-taxable-investment-gains.  Which essentially concurs with you explanation, so thanks for that...